# is arm-eabi-gcc different than arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

Is arm-eabi-gcc different than arm-linux-androideabi-gcc? Can I swap arm-eabi-gcc with arm-linux-androideabi-gcc to the agcc script from this site http://www.plausible.org/andy/agcc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, arm-eabi-gcc and arm-linux-androideabi-gcc toolchains which come with Android NDK are (somewhat) different, you can read about what arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (the newer one) is in [git](http://android.git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=platform/ndk.git;a=blob;f=docs/CHANGES.html;h=44a0e1129b4a33602c92a647f945d9ba2c11ab46;hb=refs/heads/master#l720) or in file docs/CHANGES.html in your local NDK install.

Regarding second question, you could swap arm-linux-androideabi-gcc in agcc script, but note that agcc script is pretty historical now, you doesn't need such heavy shims to build native Android code nowadays. http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html gives good intro and examples and is more recent approach (note that some examples (e.g. OpenGL ES) may be also dated as of Android 2.3). I myself use techniques described there, except that just use arm-linux-androideabi-gcc from NDK as a compiler.